# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop when key is set

Tags: reactjs, key

I'm getting 3 warnings:

1. Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
   in table
   in div (created by ModalBody)
   in ModalBody
2. Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. 
   in tr
   in thead
   in table
3. Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
   in tr
   in tbody
   in table

I've function which set data to observable variable. I've set key on outer element when use map but I still get this warning again and again.

In render function:

```
 <a 
   href="javascript:;" 
   onClick={() => this.getFieldHistory(field.name, 123, "123-123123-12")}
 >
    History
 </a>

 <Modal backdrop='static' autoFocus={true} show={this.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal}>
   <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
   <Modal.Body>
     {this.modalBody}
   </Modal.Body>
 </Modal>
```

function which get promise from service and set tbody content to observable variable:

```
    getFieldHistory(fieldName: string, subDeedId: number, guid: string): any {

    this.reportsDataService.getFieldHistory(fieldName, subDeedId, guid).then(fieldHistory => {

      runInAction.bind(this)(() => {
        this.modalBody = (
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{this.getResource(fieldName)}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
              fieldHistory.map((history, idx) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={history.date.unix().toString()}>
                    <td>{history.date.format()}</td>
                    <td>{history.fieldName}  </td>
                  </tr>
                );
                })
            }
            </tbody>
          </table>)

          this.showModal = true;
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding key value to `<table className="table table-striped" key="someuniqueid">`

Comment: tried, but still doesn't work

Comment: If this `<tr key={idx}>` does not work, your error is coming from elsewhere.

Comment: agree with Ted, Can you provide codepen or codesandbox link?

Comment: I found workaround, but still doesnt know what was the problem. Maybe I have to use more separated on components code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try adding the unique iterator index as a key: `<tr key={idx}>`

Comment: i`ve tried with the index from the map function and with timestamp of date of change which is unique

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my warnings with separating of my render logic.

```
 getFieldHistory(fieldName: string, subDeedId: number, guid: string): any {

    this.reportsDataService.getFieldHistory(fieldName, subDeedId, guid).then(fieldHistory => {

        runInAction.bind(this)(() => {
            this.modalBody = (<FieldHistoryResultUI data={fieldHistory} title={this.getResource(fieldHistory[0].fieldName)} />);

            this.showModal = true;
        });
    });
}

const FieldHistoryResultUI = (props: any) => {
    return (
    <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>{props.title}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.data.map((history: any, idx: number) => {
                return (<FieldHistoryRow key={idx} data={history} />);
            })}
        </tbody>
    </table>);
}

const FieldHistoryRow = (props: any) => {
      return (<tr><td>{props.data.date.format()}</td><td>{props.data.fieldName}</td></tr>);
}
```